# Big difference between predict and predict_proba probabilities

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I'm trying to train the model for social network posts recognition and encountered a strange thing. I'm getting a text of user's post and model predicts one class, but the highest probability corresponds to another. I give the simplest example below, but the same thing I find in other models. May be I don't understand something about the predict_proba method.

model:

```
    texts = np.array(get_train_texts()[0])
    labels = np.array(get_train_texts()[1])

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(texts, labels, 
                                       test_size=0.25, random_state=True)

    gbc_model = Pipeline([
        ('tf_idf', TfidfVectorizer()),
        ('gbc', GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators=128,
                                            max_depth=16,
                                            criterion='friedman_mse'))])

    gbc_model.fit(X_train, y_train)  
    text_to_recognize = [get_post(id, offset, access_token)]    
    label = gbc_model.predict(text_to_recognize)                
    grades = gbc_model.predict_proba(text_to_recognize)        
    grades = [f'{classes[i]}: {round(grades[0][i] * 100, 4)} %' for i in range(len(classes))]
```

output:

```
...
['science'] 
 ['science: 3.6298 %', 'cinema: 1.0597 %', 'IT: 1.5812 %', 'art: 2.1504 %', 'games: 91.5788 %']
```

So, if I chose by argmax from grades, I would get incorrect class "games" instead of "science", which corresponds good:

```
grades = gbc_model.predict_proba(text_to_recognize) 
result = classes[np.argmax(grades)]
print(result)
```

output:

```
['science'] 
 ['science: 3.6298 %', 'cinema: 1.0597 %', 'IT: 1.5812 %', 'art: 2.1504 %', 'games: 91.5788 %']
games
```

Why it happens?

Comment: Could you please update the question with the usage of `argmax` ?

Comment: Done. But interesting: if I leave the line grades = [f'{classes[i]}:... argmax gives correct result "science"

Comment: `science` is not the correct answer. Based on the probabilities, `games` has the highest probability and hence the right answer. That said, the last statement transforms `grades` into a list of string values. When you get the max of a list of strings, you're going to get the highest value based on string comparison. That's why you're observing  `science`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gbc model uses a different class order than the one you use. You select `classes[i]`, but there is no guarantee that the indices of the classes used by the `GradientBoostingClassifier` are the same.

In fact, the classifier *sorts* the classes alphabetically, making science the last class in the last, and the one with the highest probability in your example. This is why you should use the internal `gbc_model.classes_` attribute, or a `LabelEncoder`.

In other words, all is well with the Classifier.

Comment: This turned out to be completely correct. I originally created labels in the order in which my classes went in the "classes", and did not think that predicts could be placed in another. Thank!